# Decrypt AES-encrypted file, function causing a crash

Tags: c++, mfc, crash, return, aes

I am trying to write a C++ program to encrypt and decrypt certain files. Encryption works fine, but when I come to decrypt the function seems to cause a crash in the program.

Here is the function I am using for decryption:

```
    CString DecryptFile(CString csSourceFile)
    {

    CString csDecryptedFile = csSourceFile;
    CRijndael aesEncryption;

    int nPos = csDecryptedFile.ReverseFind('.');

    if(nPos == -1)
    {
        //Log("ERROR:: file name not proper");
        return CString("");
    }

    csDecryptedFile = csDecryptedFile.Left(nPos);
    csDecryptedFile += ".wav";

    FILE *fIn = fopen(csSourceFile.GetBuffer(0),"rb");
    FILE *fOut = fopen(csDecryptedFile.GetBuffer(0),"wb");

    if(!fIn || !fOut)
    {
        //Log("ERROR:: failed to Open File for encryption");
        return CString("");
    }

    int nlen = -1;

    aesEncryption.MakeKey(AM_ENC_KEY,AM_NULL_KEY,BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE);

    int nRead = 0;
    while (true) {
        char szBlockIn[EBLOCK_SIZE+1] = {0};
        char szBlockOut[BLOCK_SIZE+1] = {0};
        char szBlockDec[BLOCK_SIZE+1] = {0};

        memset(szBlockIn,0,sizeof(char)*(EBLOCK_SIZE+1));
        memset(szBlockOut,0,sizeof(char)*(BLOCK_SIZE+1));
        memset(szBlockDec,0,sizeof(char)*(BLOCK_SIZE+1));

        int nRead = fread(szBlockIn,sizeof(char),EBLOCK_SIZE, fIn);
        if(nRead <= 0) {
            break;
        }

        nlen = EBLOCK_SIZE;
        Decode(szBlockIn,szBlockOut,nlen);
        aesEncryption.DecryptBlock((char *)szBlockOut,szBlockDec);
        fwrite(szBlockDec,sizeof(char),BLOCK_SIZE,fOut);
    }

    fclose(fIn);
    fclose(fOut);

    RemoveEndTag(csDecryptedFile.GetBuffer(0));
    AfxMessageBox(csDecryptedFile);
    AfxMessageBox(_T("returning"));
    return csDecryptedFile;
}
```

This is the code snippet that calls the function:

```
CString strTest = DecryptFile(m_DecompressedTempFile);
AfxMessageBox(strTest);
```

What is strange is that the decryption is performed perfectly fine - if I got to the file location I can see the decrypted file and access it. Unfortunately, the program has to do more stuff than that, and the program just hangs immediately following. Especially weird is that, as you can see I call `AfxMessageBox(_T("returning"));` before the end of the function: this produces a message box fine. But when I call `AfxMessageBox(strTest);` from the code that runs the function, no message box is generated.

Through debugging it seems the problem is somehow routed in the while loop I have for encrypting the file, so I am wondering if I am not closing something that I should be or something? Not really sure where to do from this though, so anyone who can offer any assistance would be great !?!

Thanks in advance.

I forgot to mention that this has been working for years previously - the only recent change is that we are now compiling the code on Windows 7, whilst previously it Windows XP. Would this make a difference to anything in the function?

**Update:** It is worth noting that if I remove the while loop and run the contents of the loop just the one time, the same problem occurs. If I remove the `aesEncryption.DecryptBlock((char *)szBlockOut,szBlockDec);` then the problem disappears, but obviously I need that line in there. So the problem is routed to that function I think. Although this function exists inside the library, I hvae included it below:

```
//Decrypt exactly one block of ciphertext.
// in         - The ciphertext.
// result     - The plaintext generated from a ciphertext using the session key.
void CRijndael::DecryptBlock(char const* in, char* result)
{
    if(false==m_bKeyInit)
        throw exception(sm_szErrorMsg1);
    if(DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE == m_blockSize)
    {
        DefDecryptBlock(in, result);
        return;
    }
    int BC = m_blockSize / 4;
    int SC = BC == 4 ? 0 : (BC == 6 ? 1 : 2);
    int s1 = sm_shifts[SC][1][1];
    int s2 = sm_shifts[SC][2][1];
    int s3 = sm_shifts[SC][3][1];
    //Temporary Work Arrays
    int i;
    int tt;
    int* pi = t;
    for(i=0; i<BC; i++)
    {
        *pi = ((unsigned char)*(in++) << 24);
        *pi |= ((unsigned char)*(in++) << 16);
        *pi |= ((unsigned char)*(in++) << 8);
        (*(pi++) |= (unsigned char)*(in++)) ^= m_Kd[0][i];
    }
    //Apply Round Transforms
    for(int r=1; r<m_iROUNDS; r++)
    {
        for(i=0; i<BC; i++)
            a[i] = (sm_T5[(t[i] >> 24) & 0xFF] ^
                sm_T6[(t[(i + s1) % BC] >> 16) & 0xFF] ^
                sm_T7[(t[(i + s2) % BC] >>  8) & 0xFF] ^
                sm_T8[ t[(i + s3) % BC] & 0xFF]) ^ m_Kd[r][i];
        memcpy(t, a, 4*BC);
    }
    int j;
    //Last Round is Special
    for(i=0,j=0; i<BC; i++)
    {
        tt = m_Kd[m_iROUNDS][i];
        result[j++] = sm_Si[(t[i] >> 24) & 0xFF] ^ (tt >> 24);
        result[j++] = sm_Si[(t[(i + s1) % BC] >> 16) & 0xFF] ^ (tt >> 16);
        result[j++] = sm_Si[(t[(i + s2) % BC] >>  8) & 0xFF] ^ (tt >>  8);
        result[j++] = sm_Si[ t[(i + s3) % BC] & 0xFF] ^ tt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it that `GetBuffer(0)` call?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314880%28v=vs.60%29.aspx  Since CString is a reference counted string, you may need to call `ReleaseBuffer`

Comment: Thanks for that, a ReleaseBuffer should definitely be there. Unfortunately that's not helped the hanging problem,however :(

Comment: Maybe you should use another AES library, since the one you're using doesn't seem to have gone under a lot of peer review: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1380/A-C-Implementation-of-the-Rijndael-Encryption-Decr

Comment: I forgot to mention that this has been working for years previously - the only recent change is that we are now compiling the code on Windows 7, whilst previously it Windows XP. Would this make a difference to anything in the function?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks I hadn't found that codeacademy page; I had inherited this project from other developers you see. Could you receommend an AES library?

Comment: There is crypto++. http://www.cryptopp.com/ Just make sure you take an existing example and tailor it to your needs.  The library is stable, but has a tendency to be hard to use (my opinion).

Comment: Aren't you writing one extra block after nRead == 0?

Comment: [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/) could also be considered, it is slightly less tricky to use...

Comment: I think the problem is definitely related to the decryption function - I have included the function from the library.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks to me like you're passing in pointers to an arrays of chars, when the function is designed to accept pointers to single chars.

Comment: Is the file size always divisible by `EBLOCK_SIZE` ? In the definition of buffers you use two different constants `EBLOCK_SIZE` and `BLOCK_SIZE`, which is strange. Mysterious `Decode()` takes only one block length as a parameter, not two, which is strange. What is more strange is that `DecryptBlock()` doesn't use these constants at all, yet it somehow knows the length of the buffer. Finally, why do you allocate `szBlockIn`, `szBlockOut`, `szBlockDec` 1 byte longer than you use?

Comment: I'd run it under a debugger and set a breakpoint at the memory write of the last (supposedly unused) element of the destination array. Such breakpoint may capture the moment the code writes beyond the array boundaries. Another thought - Win XP was most likely 32bit, while Win 7 is most likely 64 bit. Even though, your program is still 32bit, the OS is significantly different and bug that you had before eventually manifests itself.

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear whether you want a C++ solution only; if you are okay with a Python solution, try the PyCrypto module. Here's what I use to zip the current directory, excepting some ignore patterns, and encrypt the .zip under ./bin (much of it is code copied from elsewhere on SO):

```
import sys
import os
import zipfile
import getpass
from contextlib import contextmanager
from hashlib import md5
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

def derive_key_and_iv(password, salt, key_length, iv_length):
    d = d_i = ''
    while len(d) < key_length + iv_length:
        d_i = md5(d_i + password + salt).digest()
        d += d_i
    return d[:key_length], d[key_length:key_length+iv_length]

def encrypt(in_file, out_file, password, key_length=32):
    bs = AES.block_size
    salt = Random.new().read(bs - len('Salted__'))
    key, iv = derive_key_and_iv(password, salt, key_length, bs)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    out_file.write('Salted__' + salt)
    finished = False
    while not finished:
        chunk = in_file.read(1024 * bs)
        if len(chunk) == 0 or len(chunk) % bs != 0:
            padding_length = (bs - len(chunk) % bs) or bs
            chunk += padding_length * chr(padding_length)
            finished = True
        out_file.write(cipher.encrypt(chunk))

def decrypt(in_file, out_file, password, key_length=32):
    bs = AES.block_size
    salt = in_file.read(bs)[len('Salted__'):]
    key, iv = derive_key_and_iv(password, salt, key_length, bs)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    next_chunk = ''
    finished = False
    while not finished:
        chunk, next_chunk = next_chunk, cipher.decrypt(in_file.read(1024 * bs))
        if len(next_chunk) == 0:
            padding_length = ord(chunk[-1])
            chunk = chunk[:-padding_length]
            finished = True
        out_file.write(chunk)

def query_yes_no(question, default="yes", quiet=False):
    """Ask a yes/no question via raw_input() and return their answer.

    "question" is a string that is presented to the user.
    "default" is the presumed answer if the user just hits <Enter>.
        It must be "yes" (the default), "no" or None (meaning
        an answer is required of the user).

    The "answer" return value is True for "yes" or False for "no".
    """
    valid = {"yes": True, "y": True, "ye": True,
             "no": False, "n": False}
    if default is None:
        prompt = " [y/n] "
    elif default == "yes":
        prompt = " [Y/n] "
    elif default == "no":
        prompt = " [y/N] "
    else:
        raise ValueError("invalid default answer: '%s'" % default)
    while True:
        if not quiet:
          sys.stdout.write(question + prompt)
        if quiet and default is not None:
          choice=default
        else:
          choice = raw_input().lower()
        if default is not None and choice == '':
            return valid[default]
        elif choice in valid:
            return valid[choice]
        else:
            sys.stdout.write("Please respond with 'yes' or 'no' "
                             "(or 'y' or 'n')\n")

dircurr=os.path.abspath('.').replace('\\','/')
dirwithenc=dircurr+'/bin'
if os.path.isfile(dirwithenc+'/bak.enc'):
  if query_yes_no("\nDo you want to decrypt '"+dirwithenc+"/bak.enc'?",'no'):
    password=getpass.getpass('\nDecryption password: ')
    with open(dirwithenc+'/bak.enc', 'rb') as in_file, open(dircurr+'/bak.zip', 'wb') as out_file:
      decrypt(in_file,out_file,password)
    print("\nFile '"+dircurr+"/bak.enc' decrypted to '"+dircurr+"/bak.zip'")
    raw_input("""
***DONE***

Press Enter...""")
    exit(0)
  else:
    print("\nAnswered 'no'")
print("\nEncrypting files will overwrite any preexisting file '"+dirwithenc+"/bak.enc'")
password=getpass.getpass('\nSet an encryption password (will not be saved): ')
print('\nZipping files, excepting certain ignore patterns...')
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(dircurr+'/bak.zip', 'w')
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath('.')):
  #Do not archive system files beginning with period
  for filename in files:
    if filename[:1]=='.':
      files.remove(filename)
  #Do not archive the binaries directory, it should just be delivered as is
  if 'bin' in subdirs:
    subdirs.remove('bin')
  #Do not archive any previous archives, or you will just make a giant snowball
  if 'bak.zip' in files:
    files.remove('bak.zip')
  if 'bak.enc' in files:
    files.remove('bak.enc')
  zf.write(dirname)
  for filename in files:
    zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
#If there was a folder 'dat' under the binaries folder, then archive it too,
#so that you have everything you need to rebuild the project
print("Including files under 'bin/dat'")
if os.path.isdir(dircurr+'/bin/dat'):
  for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(dircurr+'/bin/dat'):
    if 'bin' in subdirs:
      subdirs.remove('bin')
    zf.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
      zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
#If there were any files '*.ico' under the binaries folder, then archive them too,
#so that you have everything you need to rebuild the project
print("Including .ico files under 'bin'")
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(dircurr+'/bin'):
  for filename in files:
    if filename[-4:]=='.ico':
      zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
zf.close()
print("\nZipped to '"+dircurr+"/bak.zip'")
print("\nEncrypting zipped file and removing unencrypted zipped file...")
with open(dircurr+'/bak.zip', 'rb') as in_file, open(dirwithenc+'/bak.enc', 'wb') as out_file:
  encrypt(in_file, out_file, password)
os.remove(dircurr+'/bak.zip')
print("\nEncrypted to '"+dirwithenc+"/bak.enc'")
raw_input("""
***DONE***

Press Enter...""")
exit(0)
```